# UIwebview loading slow on iOS 6 on iphone 4,4s

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiwebview, ios6

I created one of the app using uiwebview (browser)
I tested on iphone 4,4s with iOS 5 is fine and loading very fast.
But when i tried on iphone 4,4s with iOS 6, the loading time very very slow.
How to handle this issue using programming or any other way.
Thanks

Comment: Please post your code if possible

Comment: hi Murali,Actually there's just simple coding.
just using request www.something.com... but very slow on ios6 with iphone4,4s. i tried with safari..also very slow.

Comment: May be now there is some load on your url server..

Comment: But what i can't understand was , why iOS5 on iphone4,4s faster than iOS6?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try this answer, it worked for me. Apple did change the way UIWebViews load files asynchronously.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13547296/263503