# Display multiple views serially using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, grand-central-dispatch

I have 4 tabs and all have `UIWebView`. I want that the first tab should load and displayed immediately without waiting for others to load. For which I did this in `UITabBarController` class:

```
for(UIViewController * viewController in  self.viewControllers){
        if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isSessionExpired"])
        {
            if((int)[self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController] != 4)
            {
                viewController.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];
                [viewController view];
            }
        }
    }
```

But the main thread waits for all tabs to load.
I tried this with **GCD** using `dispatch_async`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ // 1
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIViewController *firstContrl = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        firstContrl.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:firstContrl];
        [firstContrl view];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 2
            UIViewController *secContrl = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
            secContrl.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:secContrl];
            [secContrl view];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 3
                UIViewController *thirdContrl = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
                thirdContrl.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:thirdContrl];
                [thirdContrl view];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 4
                    UIViewController *fourthContrl = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
                    fourthContrl.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:fourthContrl];
                    [fourthContrl view];
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work either. It takes the same time to display the first tab.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear to me, what is the problem? You want your `UIWebView` to immediately start showing some web-content?

Comment: @orkenstein : Yes. Right now all tabs are concurrently loading. I want that initially first tab i.e. first UIWebView should load and display, so that it is active for user.  And then the rest.

Comment: Without all your custom code, how it works?
It's hard to understand this part "without waiting for others to load".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ehm.. **GCD** and **UIWebView's** `-loadRequest:` doesn't work as you think. All the code above is pretty equal to:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIViewController *firstContrl = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        firstContrl.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:firstContrl];
        [firstContrl view];

        UIViewController *secContrl = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
        secContrl.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:secContrl];
        [secContrl view];

        UIViewController *thirdContrl = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
        thirdContrl.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:thirdContrl];
        [thirdContrl view];

        UIViewController *fourthContrl = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
        fourthContrl.tabBarItem.tag = (int)[[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:fourthContrl];
        [fourthContrl view];

    });
});
```

To solve your problem you need to implement queue depends on `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`. The idea is:

1. First view controller's webView starts loading request
   asynchronously;
2. When request is loaded (or failed), webView will notify your
   delegate;
3. Notify all other view controllers with webView, to let them start
   loading their requests;

If I were you, I would implement it in next way:

```
// FirstViewController.h
extern NSString * const FirstViewControllerDidLoadWebView;

// FirstViewController.m
NSString * const FirstViewControllerDidLoadWebView=@"FirstViewControllerDidLoadWebView";
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
// notify other controllers, to let them load their web views:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FirstViewControllerDidLoadWebView
 object:nil];
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // loading failed. Try to load it few more times but anyway notify other controllers after:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FirstViewControllerDidLoadWebView
 object:nil];
}
```

After that, 'subscribe' all other(only tabs) view controllers for `FirstViewControllerDidLoadWebView` notification and load their WebView after it arrives.

For more details check [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/) and [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951)

Comment: This actually worked for me. Thanks. The UIWebView is taking some time to load. I have already asked that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272576/uiwebview-white-screen-on-every-launch-while-preloading-all-tabs). But yes, now I see a good amount of time difference. First view is loaded and displayed and then the rest are loaded. Thanks again.

Comment: Why not if we create own structure using NSOperationQueue and NSOperations, adding dependency (n+1) request depends on n operation (that means 2nd operation depends on 1st). Dependency will helpful loading 1stViewController then operation 2nd will start for 2ndViewController and so on. So your process of loading will serialized, fast, one way and synchronized.

Comment: @Tirth sure, you free to implement this in any manner you like to. I've just wrote the main idea and left implementation to your discretion. But NSOperation looks here a little overcomplicated, though.